# Process and length of time for obtaining a US J1 visa

Tags: united-states

The best candidate for a job opening in my group is Indian, lives in Europe, and has worked for (and visited / lived for short periods), a company based in a US-allied Arab country.

The Human Resources manager claims that it could take six months to get a J1 visa for the US to do background checks on someone who has lived in an Arab country.

Is this plausible? Is there a way for the employer or employee to speed up the process?

Comment: The best resource of advice is Department of State - they issue J-1 visa. No one else can give you definitive answer.

Comment: You are at the mercy of the system.  You will have to decide if that candidate is worth waiting for.  I personally would find a backup candidate that would be easier to bring in.

Answer (score 3):

I would be totally confident first, as the J1 visa is just a beginning step toward hosting someone. It is also quite expensive, [according to this page it costs $2700](http://j1visa.state.gov/sponsors/become-a-sponsor/how-to-apply/).

But the process can definitely be [less than 6 months.](http://blog.jorilallo.com/post/17144715009/how-to-intern-in-silicon-valley-and-get-a-j1-visa)

In the end, you alone will know if it's worth the effort. But do thoroughly evaluate this candidate.

Comment: Do you have anything that specifically addresses J-1 approval times for candidates who have worked in Arab countries? The link you provided does say 2 to 4 months, but it's not immediately clear if extraneous circumstances, such as being a security risk, could significantly increase that time.

Comment: This is not always true.  Especially if the country is Qatar, Yemen, or Iraq.  These are arab, countries that are nominally allied to the US but that does not equate to all citizens of these countries are ok to travel to the US.